# How to list all possible combinations of four columns with different number of records in each of them

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 4 Columns with a different number of records in each column. I want to get a new table consisting of those 4 columns and get all the possible combinations.

My initial four columns are:

```
Column A (Segment) has 10 records.
Column B (BAA Sector) has 14 records.
Column C (Terminal) has 4 records.
Column D (Hour) has 24 records.
```

[image]

The result should be a 4 columns table with 10*14*4*24 = 13440 rows.

Can you please help me to do that in Excel? I know how to do it if the number of records in each column was the same.

Comment: Could you upload the Output you are expecting to looks like !!

Comment: Hi Rajesh,the output should be 4 new columns with the same headers and 13440 rows (the possible combinations). As, I mentioned, Column A which is called Segment has 10 unique records, Column B (BAA Sector) has 14 unique records, Column C (terminal) has 4 unique columns and Column D (Hour) has 24 unique records. All the possible combinations thus are 13440. I hope that this helps

Comment: There are complex formulas to achieve this, but VBA would probably be best. Not wanting to duplicate efforts, I found this solution over at StackOverflow; https://stackoverflow.com/a/19780188.

Answer (score 1):

You can adapt this short macro to your needs:

```
Sub kombin()
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long, d As Long
    Dim pack(1 To 4) As Variant, K As Long
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet

    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    K = 1

    For a = 2 To 11
        pack(1) = s1.Cells(a, 1)
        For b = 2 To 15
            pack(2) = s1.Cells(b, 2)
                For c = 2 To 5
                    pack(3) = s1.Cells(c, 3)
                    For d = 2 To 26
                        pack(4) = s1.Cells(d, 4)
                        s2.Range("A" & K & ":D" & K) = pack
                        K = K + 1
                    Next d
                Next c
        Next b
    Next a
End Sub
```